# Converting embedded images to pictures in word document

Tags: image, ms-word

Is there any way to convert all the embedded images in a document to inline pictures in a word Document?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To convert the inserted objects as images, you may use the short cut key on the keyboard.
Click the embedded object you want to convert.
You may select the whole document first 
Press CTRL+SHIFT+F9.
Once the Object is converted to images, you may later save it to desired file format by right clicking on the object and click on save picture  as and select the format.

Source: [Microsoft](http://http:https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other/is-there-any-way-to-convert-all-objects-embedded/a22587a9-6cdd-43e7-98bf-ba726550ed99?auth=1//)

Comment: Hi.. Insterted Objects are already in png format only. So when i double click it, i Can save it as an image in my folder. But I want to convert that embedded image into an inline picture, so that i can see that picture directly in the document instead of double clicking on it and Opening.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46090069/15206047, because I think he gave you the right one:

I think you meant that when you create a document in word and add the images as fields, so they update when you change them, then how do you convert those fields to plain images? For example to share the file with someone who doesn't want a pdf but a word and doesn't have the images on his computer?

Click shift + F9 to "reveal" the field codes. Then click ctrl + shift + F9 to unlink them. Click shift + F9 to make sure they are gone. Then save the file.

If what you meant was the opposite and you mistyped "inline" and wanted to say "online", then you have to go to insert - quickparts field - includepicture - mark data not stored with document and if you want to, preserve formatting during updates.

I always prefer to use Latex but sometimes people need to see a document in word...and it's always a hassle.

Comment: Please [edit] to change the reference from "previous answer" (which can get confusing) to a link via URL. Use the "share" link below the target answer.

Comment: @Yunnosch Great, thanks! I just saw it.